# ASP.NET Webform - How to place FormView and GridView next to each other

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, formview

In my webform I have a gridview and a formview.  The formview always appears under the gridview.  How do I move the Formview to the right of the gridview?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

GridView and FormView are render as `tables`, so one way is to use one warper table to place it side by side. Of course some will say that tables are not modern design and its better to use divs... ok this is just a fast solution.

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <asp:GridView></asp:GridView>    
        </td>
        <td>
            <asp:FormView></asp:FormView>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: This will work (although you may want to set `td{ vertical-align: top; }`), but as Aristos mentioned using tables for layout is generally frowned upon (mainly because of responsive design) so you may want to look into a CSS grid framework like Bootstrap - which is almost standard these days.

Comment: @zgood he did not know how to view source code and see how to place them side by side, and you talk about bootstrap ;-)... maybe after some months...

Comment: Thanks, Aristos.  This is exactly what I wanted.

Comment: @Aristos eh, you're probably right, but still worth a mention so he knows that this isn't the standard these days.